# RABL collection appears empty in template but not in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

I'm currently using rabl-rails 0.5.3 and Rails 4.2.6

I've got this problem where I'm attempting to render a collection of my College objects from the index method of a Rails controller.

Here's a simplified version of the index method in my controller:

```
  def index
    @colleges = College.all

    puts @colleges.count

    render 'api/data_bridge/colleges/show'
  end
```

I see '100' for the output of the puts statement there. Some clearly @colleges is not empty.

Here is the rabl index template:

```
puts "---===========================-"
puts @colleges.inspect
puts "---===========================-"
collection @colleges
```

In my server output I'm seeing those puts statements looking like:

```
---===========================-
nil
---===========================-
```

When I dump the @colleges in the controller, it's definitely not nil. I can't figure out what happened to the data between the controller and the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation as source for my claims: https://github.com/ccocchi/rabl-rails#overview

Your rabl file should look like this:

```
puts "---===========================-"
puts :@colleges.inspect
puts "---===========================-"
collection :@colleges
```

This was their example:

```
# app/views/post/index.rabl
collection :@posts
attributes :id, :title, :subject
child(:user) { attributes :full_name }
node(:read) { |post| post.read_by?(@user) }
```

Pay close attention to the ":" in front of the symbol. Here is why:

> The fact of compiling the template outside of any rendering context
>   prevent us to use any instances variables (with the exception of node)
>   in the template because they are rendering objects. So instead, you'll
>   have to use symbols of these variables.For example, to render the
>   collection @posts inside your PostController, you need to use :@posts
>   inside of the template.

Comment: excellent. That got me a step closer. Now I'm getting an error about "Unknown primary key for table college in model College". The primary key on that model is 'college_id' instead of 'id'. I tried specifying `set_primary_key = 'college_id'` in the model, but it gets the same error either way

Comment: Please mark this as solved if I solved your original problem! You should really just stick to convention. Don't override this in the model. Generate a migration `rails g migration AddPrimaryKeyToColleges id:primary_key`. Then run `rails db:migrate`. If you don't want to migrate, you need to use the right syntax: `self.primary_key = "college_id"`

Comment: changing the column primary id is out of my hands. It's something that was implemented prior to my arrival and is adamantly insisted upon by the bulk of the team I'm on. In fact, given the task I'm undertaking, I can't change anything about the database--I'm just reading from it. I'll mark this as solved. Just trying to resist opening another question...